# How to retrieve environment variables from XP?

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

What is a way for a novice user to retreive the environment variables on an XP machine?

I need to ask a user to do this but it needs to be very simple and easy to copy into an email.

Answer (score 1):

Is better use SET on CMD to get all enviroiment variable.
PATH only returns you PATH variable not all variables in the enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could put this in a batch file and have them just double-click it.

```
@echo off
set > paths.txt
```

Then have the user email the paths.txt to you.

Comment: Too difficult for a novice user. They won't want to use the command prompt.

Comment: Put that in a batch file then?

Comment: I have to advise over the phone.

Comment: why not exchange mails instead? I'm sure both parties will be attentive to incoming mails.

Comment: Host the batch script online, so they can download it and run it on their own computer?

Comment: If they are emailing you, then why can't you email them? I can't think of a simpler method.

Comment: They can't run scripts or any other programs.  Very locked down corporate environment.  Needs to be some kind of in-built windows thing.

Comment: @CraigJ: `set` is the build in way. There is nothing in the GUI that will allow a copy of all of the environment. (I assume machine properties and regedit are both unavailable in a locked down environment.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting information from GUI thing is much easier and simple as getting it from command-prompt or batch file for a novice user.

Whenever I want to check my environment variables by:

1. Press `Window key` + `R` >
2. Type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` and Press `Enter`
3. It opens up a window which has `Environment Variables` button, Click it, or Press `Alt`+`n`

It will open up the dialog that gives information about all Environment variables.

Comment: Will that work for XP?